# Function to get daily metrics by fetching a record or evaluating a formula

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner

I have react-redux application that allows to track different metrics on daily basis. Each metric can either have Records or store math function to calculate values. State stores normalized Metrics and Records.

This function returns either a calculated value or stored value for certain date.

```
export const getMetricRecordForDate = (state, metric_id, date) => {
  const resultMetric = state.metrics[metric_id]
  let result = {decimal_value: 0, date: date}
  if (resultMetric.formula) { //formula format: '_idOfMetric_*_idOfAnotherMetric_'
    let args = {}

    const metrics = resultMetric.formula.scan(/_(.*?)_/g) //Array: [..,'_idOfMetric_']
    const l = metrics.length
    for (var i=0; i<l; i++) {
      const key = "_"+metrics[i]+"_"
      args[key] = getMetricRecordForDate(state, state.metrics[metrics[i]].id, date).decimal_value

    }

    let decimal_value
    try { // statements to try args format: {_idOfMetric_: value}
      decimal_value = math.eval(resultMetric.formula, args)
    }
    catch (e) {
      decimal_value = 0;
    }

    result.decimal_value = decimal_value
  } else {
    const records = getMetricRecords(metric_id, state)
    let metricRecord
    if (records.length > 0) {
      for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        if (moment(records[i].date).isSame(date, 'day')) {
          metricRecord = records[i]
          break
        }
      }
    }
    if (metricRecord) {
      result = metricRecord
    }
  }
  return result

}
```

The structure of state:

```
{state: 
  {metrics: {1: {id: 1, name: 'name', records: [1, 2]} },
  {records: {1: {id: 1, decimal_value: 0, date: '01-01-2017', metric_id: 1},
            {2: {id: 1, decimal_value: 0, date: '02-01-2017', metric_id: 1}
  }
}
```

So, right now this function is very slow especially for recursive calls. I was wondering if it could be optimized.

Here is the getMetricRecords function:

```
export const getMetricRecords = (metric_id, state) => {
  return state.metrics[metric_id].records.map( id => state.records[id])
}
```

I would appreciate any help (I am new to Javascript).

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Code Review!  Please review [How do I ask a good Question?](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) Specifically, it is best to explain what the code does.  This is especially true in the title.

Comment: Can you add an example of you data? How you know its a heavy function, what have you meassured? What is math.eval?

Comment: I edited post to clarify. Sorry, it wasn't clear before. math.eval is function of mathjs library. It calculates math expression based on formula like: '_idOfMetric1_*_idOfMetric2_' and substitutes _ids_ with values from object provided as second argument @juvian

Answer (score 1):

Help you to figure out how to optimize this function is not easy from outside.

Optimization is hard staff and start by collecting numbers.

If you think your function is slow, you should first measure the amount of time that your function run, the size of data that processes, the memory involved and the CPU cycles used.

You could do this with a profiler included in all the modern browsers.

With this numbers you could understand if your function is really bad as you think it is or maybe not.

You said that it is slow, but how about the staff that have to do. In a part you speak about arrays of arrays.

Now if the function is just handling too much its helpful as told us we have to change our approach as the way we though to do is not fit the reality. So no need on wasting time to optimize a function rather find a way to reduce the problem in a manner that is faster to compute.

If the function is very bad, instead, according with our measurements, than it's time to profile inside and start to look where we consume all that time.

Keep the worst part and try to understand what is the problem and fix this. An then move on to the next less worse.

**UPDATE**

As was clarified later, the recursion is connected with complex formulas and not with stored values.

A part that is still not clear to me:

```
const resultMetric = state.metrics[metric_id]
...
const records = getMetricRecords(metric_id, state)
```

In *getMetricRecords()* you just look for *resultMetric* again. As it is an access by key is not an big issue, but for sake of code clarity, if it is the same thing you could consider to move the code of *getMetricRecords()*. It is not so big staff.

```
const records = resultMetric.records.map(id => state.records[id])
```

the following part could even be simplified:

```
let metricRecord
if (records.length > 0) {
  for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
    if (moment(records[i].date).isSame(date, 'day')) {
      metricRecord = records[i]
      break
    }
  }
}
if (metricRecord) {
  result = metricRecord
}
```

Avoiding to check the length of the *records* as the for loop already do, and remove the variable *metricRecord*:

```
for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
    if (moment(records[i].date).isSame(date, 'day')) {
      result = records[i]
      break
    }
}
```

Of course I don't think this will solve your performance issue, sorry. :(
I just like to remove not-needed code.

About *records* if is a huge list, and memory is not an issue, you could consider to have an object/map with *date* as the key so you could avoid the for loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added comments to clarify (I am working on expressing myself better). So, from time measurements it seems that recursion increases performance time exponentially: if a formula contains a metric that is also a formula, time is squared. I am thinking of replacing with iteration but can't figure out how. I also do not store calculated values, which I probably should but don't know how. This is why I calculate first.

Comment: Ok, that's because the formula is a graph that contains formulas that could be evaluated and formulas that are composed of other formulas. So yes recursion is a good pattern for such data structures.

Comment: To better explain your case, consider to provide an example of the formulas data structure.

Comment: Again thanks for your reply. Both Metrics and Records are stored by ids. Metric object has an array of Record ids that belong to it. To get Records of certain Metric I use getMetricRecords() function which loops through array of ids and returns Records. I updated answer to show the structure of state